# I imported version 4.1.1 but there isn't any module dependencies in 'Project Structure>Dependencies>app'

Tags: android-studio, opencv

After importing process sync was succesful but I had to add this as a dependency in my 'app' but I couldn't see anything.

Note: At configurations button, Opencv's symbol is an android symbol but there is a cross at the top of its head and when I was importing it I wrote its location and its name was "java".

Comment: can you share some more screenshots of your project structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with changing OpenCV's build.gradle's apply plugin: 'com.android.application' to '.......library'.